# I am trying to access a camera in Python and it is showing error on line 7

Tags: python, opencv

It is showing an error and I don't how to resolve this error. Plus I am new to Python.

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
hand_detector = mp.solutions.hands.Hands()
while True:
     _, frame = cap.read()
    rgb_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.BGR2RGB)
    output = hand_detector.process(rgb_frame)
    hands = output.multi_hand_landmarks
    print(hands)
    cv2.imshow('Virtual Mouse', frame)
    cv2.waitkey(1)
```

Error:

```
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\virtual mouse 2\main.py", line 7, in <module>
    rgb_frame = cv2.cvtColor( frame, cv2.BGR2RGB )
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'BGR2RGB'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: can u post error log please

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I don't use `cv2` myself, but I added the tag for it to attract people who do. However, this is not a good question because the title is vague and it's not clear what exactly you need help with, like for example, do you know what the error means? Please read [ask], then [edit] as needed.

Comment: the `cv2` tag is deprecated. just tag OpenCV. this question amounts to a typo (error of laziness/inattention) because OP simply didn't look up the correct identifier in the docs. it's almost correct. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

It's a syntax error, you just need to change from `cv2.BGR2RGB` to `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`

It should work fine. Let me know if it doesn't.

```
rgb_frame = cv2.cvtColor( frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\virtual mouse 2\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    output = hand_detector.process(rgb_frame)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\virtual mouse 2\venv\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\hands.py", line 153, in process
    return super().process(input_data={'image': image})
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\virtual mouse 2\venv\lib\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 352, in process
    if data.shape[2] != RGB_CHANNELS:
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but how is that a syntax error? If OP's trying to use a name that the library doesn't have, what does that have to do with Python syntax?

Comment: it's a **typo**, not a syntax error exactly. OP thought they knew the identifier but it needs an additional `COLOR_` prefixed. that is such a trivial issue, it's supposed to be classified as a typo, and the question **closed**.